# Texonomy template not showing filterd categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am created categories for my custom post type using regiter_texonomy. If I click on category it navigates to texonomy_template but not showing any custom posts. Why it is showing empty posts?

index.php

```
<?php 
 $defaults = array(
        'taxonomy'            => 'portfolio_category',
        'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' )
    );
wp_list_categories($defaults); ?>
```

texonomy-portfolio_category.php

```
<?php 
if(have_posts()):
    echo 'Yes';
else:
    echo 'No';
endif;
?>
```

But it showing an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

there can be possibility that you might have empty Categories and due to that they might not being displayed using `wp_list_categories` so just try out the below args that should work.

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
  'hide_empty'          => false,  
  'taxonomy'            => 'portfolio_category',
  'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' )
);

wp_list_categories($defaults); 
?>
```

Comment: categories ae showing.But when i click on any category posts are not showing.

Comment: please post the complete Loop here so that i can check out as you only added if(have_posts()):
    echo 'Yes';
else:
    echo 'No';
endif;

Comment: $args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'portfolio'
);
$a = get_posts( $args );

This is showing ok.But when i use have_post() no posts showing of perticular selected category

Comment: if you are trying it over the texonomy-portfolio_category.php than it should have loaded by default the latest post from the category page which you are checking do have while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // loop content endwhile; loop define on that page as there is basically no need of $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' ); $a = get_posts( $args ) as those posts will be auto populated by WP_Query upon accessing the page

Comment: Ya.I just tried using while(have_posts()):the_post().It is showing nothing end .Basically have_posts() return true if is there any posts.But it is showing false.